# Can someone explain this uncertainty estimation technique to me

Tags: maximum-likelihood, uncertainty

I have been trying to understand a method of finding parameter uncertainties resulting from maximum likelihood estimation. Unfortunately the document I have is not in the public domain however I have found what I think is exactly the same method used in a paper from medicine. Having found it somewhere else has made me more confident that the method is correct but I still don't follow how/why it works.

The paper is on pub-med at http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11316558

The section I don't get is 'calculation of the probability distribution of the parameters', on page 150. Is this a way of creating a 'credible interval' assuming a uniform prior? I have never dipped into credible intervals so I don't really follow. It's the 'normalising the parameter space to 1' that confuses/worries me.

The section I don't understand proceeds as follows. 
1) Calculate the likelihood L(x| a,b) for each point on the grid of parameter a vs. parameter b - so far so good.

The next step is where I get lost, the calculation of P(a,b|x) from the above grid. 
2) Sum together all the values on the grid and divide the value in each cell by this total - producing what I think is a 2D histogram with integral 1. The paper asserts that as P(a,b|x) is proportional to L(x|a,b) - which I agree with - then this normalised grid gives P(a,b|x). Is this simply a 'credible interval' with a uniform prior of 1. Perhaps what I don't understand is how the denominator in Bayes' theorem P(x) is given by the integral of a grid of L(a,b|x) for a range of a and b. Surely just by moving the grid one would change the values.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain a little, as not everyone will have access to that journal. Just from the abstract it looks to me as if they're talking about prediction of new observations, & contrasting the 'ML method' - plugging maximum-likelihood estimates into the model & using it as if they were known exactly - with the 'PD method' - which presumably takes uncertainty in parameter estimates into account when making predictions & sounds like some sort of [predictive likelihood](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1177012175).

Comment: They have fitted a model with two free parameters. To show their uncertainties they start much as I would, produce a 2-D grid showing L(x|a,b). At this point I would construct contours using likelihood ratios and Wilkes' theorem ln(L) = Ln(L)min +0.5 or whatever. They appear to have normalised the sum of the likelihoods on the grid to one and taken the resulting number between 0 and 1 for a given point on the grid to be P(a,b|x). This doesn't seem intuitively sensible to me, although it maybe. I'll dig the ref out again and copy in the relevent section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described, you're right in equating this to a Bayesian calculation of the joint posterior parameter density using flat priors, & if they call it P(a,b|x) that must be what they mean.  There might be another, non-Bayesian, justification for the calculation, though.